# Including a second jar file that's not a dependency into a fat onejar

Tags: gradle, onejar

I have a project that only builds the fat onejar file for testing purposes. Thus, there's a separate testing class that I don't want as a dependency to the main source, but I *do* want it included into the onejar. Odd scenario, I know.

I'm using the `com.smokejumperit.gradle.OneJarPlugin` plugin ([source here](https://github.com/RobertFischer/gradle-plugins/blob/master/src/main/groovy/OneJarPlugin.groovy)), and clearly it gets the list of files to include in the onejar here:

```
project.task('oneJar', dependsOn:[project.tasks.jar, project.tasks.typedefOneJar]) {
    ...
    inputs.files([jar.outputs.files, project.configurations.getByName("compile"), project.configurations.getByName("runtime")])
```

`jar.output.files` is used for publishing, so I don't want a this second jar file being published, and the two `project.configurations` would define dependencies for the main source jar, and I don't want this second jar to be a dependency of that either.

This second jar file is built with a task:

```
task integrationJar(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.integrationTest.output
    classifier = 'integration'
}
```

... so I can access the resulting FileCollection via `integrationJar.outputs.files`. If there was a clear way to add that to `oneJar.input.files`, I'd be golden, but I can't figure out how to do that. I've tried something like this:

```
oneJar {
    dependsOn 'integrationJar'
    println integrationJar.outputs.files.getAsPath()
    inputs.files.add(integrationJar.outputs.files)
    println inputs.files.getAsPath()
}
```

... but the result for the last print is still missing the integration jar file.

Ideas?

Comment: Just put a dummy class in the main source that depends on the jar in question. Ugly but effective.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, exactly. Can you give an example? The integration jar file is separate because it has some dependencies I don't want the main source to have (like jetty). Do you mean a class that simply loads the jar file into the classpath or something? Not sure what that might look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the implementation of that plugin, but I'd be surprised if `inputs.files` determined what gets included. (Usually, `inputs` is just consumed by Gradle's up-to-date check.) I recommend to try the [gradle-one-jar](https://github.com/rholder/gradle-one-jar) plugin, which appears to be more flexible.